# Timestamp values not inserting sometime in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, timestamp

The timestamp value in Stored procedure is `'30-APR-14 12.00.00.000000 AM'`.
The parameter list:

```
XXXXX(
   P_CAT_PRG_ID     NUMBER,
   P_CATALOG_ID     NUMBER,
   P_PRG_ELE_ID     NUMBER,
   **P_ELE_CLOSE_DATE TIMESTAMP**,
   -- P_UNIT_PACK      NUMBER,
   P_UNIT_PRICE NUMBER,
   P_CURRENCY   VARCHAR2,
   P_CREATED_BY NUMBER
   ) AS
```

While executing this sp in "Oracle sql developer" I am giving the value as `'03/Apr/14'`.

The insert query inside that sp:

```
INSERT INTO CCCXXXX
      (CAT_PRG_ID,
       CATALOG_ID,
       PRG_ELE_ID,
       ELE_CLOSE_DATE,
       UNIT_PRICE,
       CURRENCY,
       CREATED_BY,
       CREATED_DATE)
    VALUES
      (0,
       P_CATALOG_ID,
       P_PRG_ELE_ID,
       P_ELE_CLOSE_DATE,
       P_UNIT_PRICE,
       P_CURRENCY,
       P_CREATED_BY,
       SYSTIMESTAMP);
```

The Error:

> ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Could you please help me ...

Comment: `V_CAT_PRG_ID`? Not `P_CAT_PRG_ID`?

Comment: values is zero only, some lines are skipped to simplify.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the timestamp value in stored procedure'? How exactly are you calling the procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Issue was not there in insert query,

```
IF **TO_TIMESTAMP(V_CAT_STATUS, 'DD-MON-RR HH:MI:SS.FF AM')** <= SYSDATE AND V_IS_PS_CREATED = 1 THEN

UPDATE CATALOG_MASTER SET IS_PS_CREATED = 0 WHERE CATALOG_ID=P_CATALOG_ID;

END IF;
```

The bold string is the changes.I was missed TO_TIMESTAMP instead was using TO_DATE